# Crosswalk for iOS not working with iOS SDK 10.1.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, crosswalk

I am making an iOS app using crosswalk iOS web application runtime version 1.2.0. It works well till iOS SDK 9.2 but with latest iOS SDK 10.1.1 it gives compile time errors about Swift syntax as crosswalk for iOS is written in both Swift (maybe 1.0 or 1.2 Swift version) & Objective-C. As it is written in old Swift version (older than 2.3) I am getting compile time errors about Swift syntax in the library with latest iOS SDK 10.1.1 while compiling in Xcode 8.

When I set "use legacy swift language version" setting to yes from unspecified the above happens i.e. I get compile time errors about Swift syntax in library. & when I convert crosswalk iOS library to Swift 3 or 2.3 using Xcode 8 using crosswalk iOS SDK 10.1.1 it still throws compile time errors about the syntax in .swift files. When I set "use legacy swift language version" setting to no still get compile time errors about syntax. When I set "use legacy swift language version" to unspecified it gives `"Use Legacy Swift Language Version" (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.`

Building the app with library with iOS SDK version 9.2 & installing the .ipa file in iPhone 5s using version 10.1.1 the app installs but is not running. It simply starts & then shuts down instantly.

I integrated the crosswalk library using cocoapods.

I need help in using crosswalk iOS library 1.2.0 (which is latest as till Nov. 2016) with latest iOS SDK 10.1.1.

Please let me know if any clarification is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the complete (Swift part) library to latest Swift version solved the problem. Just had to solve syntax errors from old Swift version to latest Swift version.